# HTML Use content/Input from a user in order to overlay his text over a picture

Tags: html, image, input, content-management-system

I'm quite new to html and in order to help a friend create a Website, I need to get an Input from a User and overlay it over a picture. I'm using a WCMS and I doubt there aren't any options to solve this problem without using HTML.

Thank you!

I already tried to create some text boxes and already implemented the image, but I don't know how to get the Input and write it on the picture

Comment: What kind of WCMS are you using? If i understood you correctly, you want the user to type in something into an INPUT and then show the VALUE from the INPUT over an image as a text, is it right? Can you give us a link to the work you're already done?

Comment: I'm using a german WCMS. I doubt its known internationally. Unfortunately I can't share a link because the website isn't supposed to be online already.  But I can use an HTML element where I can write css and html code. I already implemented the picture and a text field, but I dont know how to get the Input and show it over the image.